# How to create a function that returns a function of the product of a list of functions

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I would like to create a function that returns a function of the product of a list of functions. The list of functions should be of variable length and the functions should have different parameters.

E.g.:

```
def f(a, b, **kwargs):
    return a + b

def g(c, d, **kwargs):
    return c + d

def product_function(function_list, **kwargs):
    ...
    <create function that returns product function of functions in 
     function_list>
    ...
    return <productfunction>
```

In the example above this would be something like:

```
my_function = product_function([f,g])
```

This should return a function that can be used *as if it was defined as:*

```
def my_function(a, b, c, d):
    return f(a, b) * g(c, d)
```

I would like to use this for iterating over a list of combinations of factors and optimising parameters for these combinations to select the most predictive one in a data science project.

Comment: How should kwargs be handled? If you don't need them, don't add them in.

Comment: I assume the kwargs should be passed to each function in `function_list`?

Comment: @abccd  I had added the **kwargs because I thought all parameters would be entered into all functions. Apparently I should not have added **kwargs at all.

Comment: @Aran-Fey No not necessarily, only the function to which the parameters are relevant

Comment: What is the reason for downvoting? I think two people understood my question perfectly and gave very nice solutions that I think were not trivial.

Comment: Just a guess, but it might be because you didn't explain how the `**kwargs` should be handled, or because you didn't post your own attempt at writing `product_function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some help from the introspection utilities in the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module.

Specifically, I used [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) to find each function's positional and keyword arguments, and [`Signature.bind_partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.bind_partial) to prevent clashes between positional and keyword arguments. The following is a generic implementation of a function that combines other functions:

```
import inspect

def generic_operator_function(operator_function, default_value,
                              function_list, **kwargs):
    POSITIONALS = {inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY,
                   inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD}
    KEYWORDS = {inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD,
                inspect.Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY}

    # if no functions were given, return the default value
    if not function_list:
        return lambda: default_value

    # for each function in the list, find out how many positional
    # arguments it accepts. Also find out which keyword arguments
    # it accepts.
    arg_maps = []
    kwarg_names = []
    for func in function_list:
        sig = inspect.signature(func)
        params = sig.parameters.values()

        # count the positional arguments and map them to
        # parameter names
        bound_args = sig.bind_partial(**kwargs).arguments
        arg_map = [param.name for param in params if param.kind in POSITIONALS
                                                  and param.name not in bound_args]
        arg_maps.append(arg_map)

        # find the names of all keyword arguments
        if any(param.kind == inspect.Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD for param in params):
            kwnames = True
        else:
            kwnames = {param.name for param in params if param.kind in KEYWORDS}
        kwarg_names.append(kwnames)

    # return a function that iterates through the function_list and
    # multiplies all results
    def combined_func(*args, **inner_kwargs):
        value = default_value

        i = 0
        for func, arg_map, kwnames in zip(function_list, arg_maps, kwarg_names):
            # if the function takes **kwargs, pass all kwargs. Otherwise, pass
            # only those that it supports.
            kw_arguments = kwargs.copy()
            kw_arguments.update(inner_kwargs)
            if kwnames is not True:
                kw_arguments = {k: v for k, v in kw_arguments.items() if k in kwnames}

            # take the next batch of arguments, but only those that aren't already
            # provided as keyword arguments
            arg_map = [arg for arg in arg_map if arg not in kw_arguments]
            numparams = len(arg_map)
            arguments = args[i:i+numparams]
            kw_arguments.update({arg: value for arg, value in zip(arg_map, arguments)})

            # call the function
            retval = func(**kw_arguments)
            value = operator_function(value, retval)

            i += numparams

        return value

    return combined_func
```

With this, you can easily define a bunch of functions similar to your `product_function`:

```
import operator

def product_function(*args, **kwargs):
    return generic_operator_function(operator.mul, 1, *args, **kwargs)

def sum_function(*args, **kwargs):
    return generic_operator_function(operator.add, 0, *args, **kwargs)

def append_function(*args, **kwargs):
    return generic_operator_function(lambda x, y: x+[y], [], *args, **kwargs)
```

```
>>> my_function = product_function([f,g])
>>> my_function(1,2, 3,4)
21
>>> sum_function([f,g])(1,2, 3,4)
10
>>> append_function([f,g])(1,2, 3,4)
[3, 7]
```

And it correctly passes on only those keyword arguments that each function supports:

```
>>> p = product_function([f,g], a=1, c=2)
>>> p(3, 4)
24
```

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Would it be possible to give arguments of `f` and `g` default values and only fill in some arguments, like: `product_function(a=1, c=1)`

Comment: @Frits Updated. See the example at the very bottom.

Comment: I wrote my follow up question wrongly, I wanted to ask how to implement it such that `p=product_function([f,g])` and then call `p(a=1, c=2)`

Comment: @Frits But then where do the values for `b` and `d` come from? Do the `f` and `g` functions have default values for those parameters?

Comment: Yes, let's say `f(a=0, b=0)` and `g(c=0, d=0)` so when calling `p` we only set arguments we want

Comment: Great work! I had to add **kwargs to both `g` and `f` to make it work. I'm very happy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Frits Thanks for pointing that out; it should be fixed now and also work without kwargs.